# Card.io Android SDK - Is it possible to modify color of the action bar on "Card Details" screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, card.io

I have the card.io SDK integrated with my android app. On the screen titled "Card Details" that displays the scanned CC along with the expiry date, is there a way to change the color of the action bar? Use of EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME does not work for my requirement.

I've noticed in the iOS SDK, there are properties like navigationBarStyle & navigationBarTintColor that enable this modification. Is there something similar on Android?

Answer (score 0):

No, `EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME` was meant to be a sufficient mechanism for Android to set the color of the action bar.  If it's not changing the color to match the theme, then there's a bug.  Please file the bug in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/).